# React Native useLayoutEffect with firebase function in it is not running after button click, why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am calling getDoc function inside useLayoutEffect. On the first page navigation works perfectly. Then in this, I click a button that is updating firebase firestore. After this, I want useLayoutEffect to get firestore data again and refresh my view but it does not. Now I have to return to the previous page and come back to the current page to refresh it.

Here is my useLayoutEffect function and also View code:

```
 useLayoutEffect(() => {
    async function GetMessages() {
      const docRef = doc(
        db,
        "chat",
        auth.currentUser.email,
        "chatWith",
        route.params.id
      );
      const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);
      
      messages.push({
        id: docSnap.id,
        
          messages: docSnap.data().messages,
          message_time: docSnap.data().msg_time,
      
      })
      ;
      setMessages([messages]);
      console.log(messages)
   
    }
    GetMessages();
  }, [route]);
```

```
 <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "white" }}>
      <StatusBar style="light" />
      <KeyboardAvoidingView
        behavior={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "padding" : "height"}
        style={styles.container}
        keyboardVerticalOffset={90}
      >
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>
          <>
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// This is the part
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            <ScrollView>
            {
            messages.map((message,index) =>   <View key={index}>
                    
                    <Text>{message[0].messages}</Text>
                  </View>)}
            </ScrollView>
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            <View style={styles.footer}>
              <TextInput
                value={input}
                onChangeText={(text) => setInput(text)}
                placeholder="Mesaj yaz..."
                style={styles.textInput}
              />
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={sendMessage} activeOpacity={0.5}>
                <Ionicons
                  style={{ marginHorizontal: 8 }}
                  name="send"
                  size={24}
                  color="#f25551"
                />
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    </SafeAreaView>
```

I want useLayoutEffect to get firestore data again and refresh my view.

It is a clone of whatsapp chat and I want to display my message in the chats part after I write and click to send button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`useLayoutEffect` is just to make some DOM changes before React paints DOM elements.

React starts by rerendering the component first, and when it comes to JSX, both `useLayoutEffect` and `useEffect` are not fired yet so when it comes to here

```js
<Text>{message[0].messages}</Text>
```

`message` is still an empty array then when it finishes rendering the component, just before painting, `useLayoutEffect` fires to makes some DOM changes, it may also rerender the component if there are state updates inside it and after painting,  `useEffect` runs 
so here, to fetch data, using `useEffect` is recommended you just initialize your `message` state to `[]`:

```js
const [message, setMessage] = useState([])
//...
useEffect(() => {
 // useLayoutEffect code
},[route])
```

finally, you add this condition to handle the first render when `message` is still empty before `useEffect` runs:

```js
{
 message.length && messages.map((message,index) => ....)
}
```

---

Now for the button that should trigger `useLayoutEffect` to run again and fetch data, I cannot find it in the code but `useEffect` and `useLayoutEffect` both fire when the component first mount ( that's why when you  return to the previous page and come back to the current page you have the new data) and also fire when their dependency array values change, so if the button you click is not updating `route` then don't expect `useLayoutEffect` to fire